# Boy asks 'How about pie?'

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the title of a 1950s science fiction movie, involving an astronomer trying to decode some extraterrestrial signal, where the juvenile (male) character asks 'how about pi?' which all the adults interpret as a foolish 'how about pie?' question.

Comment: This reminds me of the Fredric Brown story "Pi in the Sky", but that was a novelette and never a movie as far as i know.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - On the same note...  I seem to recall a poem in the back of '[The Mathematical Magpie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Magpie)' that ended with the following verse regarding putting computers in Orbit: "It might be more sound, were they here, on the ground.. but People want Pi in the sky."

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/2e/8b/8f2e8bd4b20a2910f4c7bd5b9b06dea7.jpg

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197905/1950s-movie-includes-the-line-how-about-pi (which is newer but has an answer confirmed via comment)

Answer (score 7):

Red Planet Mars (1952)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_Mars

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045073/

About 22.5 min into the film.

> "how about pi?" ...

The film's a pretty deep trip into the early 50's American psyche, *shudder*.

Comment: It was quite a treat for someone growing up in the 1970's! (I've just linked this [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25064/7982))

Comment: just after `22:00` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OXYLCVUaCc