# 50/60’s sci fi movie using Pi to communicate to aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

What 50/60’s sci fi movie uses Pi to communicate with aliens?

Comment: Do you remember any other details?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. Particularly how/why the aliens used pi. Who was communicating with them and how was it used?

Answer (score 7):

As per [1950's movie includes the line "How about Pi?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197905/) (disclaimer: answer mine), possibly [*Red Planet Mars*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045073/) (1952).

From IMDb:

> An American scientist is able to contact and communicate with Mars with shattering political, economic, and spiritual repercussions.

And from the earlier question:

> Their kid says "How about Pi?" (the number) while eating a piece of pie, suggesting that the number Pi be used as a code to check if the signals are intelligent by testing if they recognize the sequence of digits and continue it.